# How can I connect two bones head to head (not head to tail)?

Tags: rigging, bones

I have a problem with my Armature, to be more specific, it's 3 bones which makes the problem.
I have a Pony character which I wanted to rig, so I made an armature which works great, but I can't connect my Root bone to the Front legs and neck section. (see picture) I watched a few tutorials on the internet and read [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21239/join-bones-in-a-armature), but all they said was to flip the bone from the Head to Tail and connect them together. I don't want to flip, but connect Head to Head.

Can I do this? I can't move the legs and the neck/head section from the Root(Spine) bone. Here are some pictures. I marked the Root bone with a White circle and the other bones which I want to connect with Red circles.

[image: Here is the image from the root bone, legs and neck] 
[image: No connection, I move the bone but legs and neck are not moving]

Comment: I want to congratulate you on coming back and sticking with your question. (I've seen other new users just leave.) Not only did I close and reopen your question after reading your edit, but I think I may of solved your problem too. You already fit in with the SE Q/A system very well. Welcome to the site, I hope you can find and give much help here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can not "connect" (parent) a bone's head to another head, nor does tail to tail work. As I showed in [my answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/21241/2217) parenting bones to other bones is the normal way to connect them. The manual's page about [armature structure](https://www.blender.org/manual/rigging/armatures/structure.html) explains how bones link together.

However, there is another option, using the bone [*Child Of* constraint](https://www.blender.org/manual/rigging/constraints/relationship/child_of.html#child-of-constraint).<sup>*</sup>
In pose mode, Under the Bone Constraint tab of the properties window add a Child Of constraint to each bone you want to be connected.
Simply set the *Target* to be the armature, and then your "root" bone.
The *Set Inverse* button will keep the bones position. (as you may of noticed it jumped to the targeted bone's head).
The *Clear Inverse* button will move the bone to the traget's location.

[image: Child Of constraint]

The downside to this method is it will not work in edit mode.

---

<sup>*</sup> The [manual](https://www.blender.org/manual/rigging/constraints/relationship/child_of.html#child-of-constraint) warns against using a Child Of constraint to create chains of bones.
I don't see any problem in this instance, and it is the only way to connect bones' head to another head.

Comment: Yeah, okay, i fixed it, i just made a Root bone and from there i go whoever i want, it's a bit complicated how all this Rigging works aparentely :/ I just want to make a game with animations... I saw a few tutorials about rigging, but this all was just about Humanoid characters but not animals... 

I don't know if that what i made would give me some issues with animating, but this was the only sulution for me 'cause when i made it with your tutorial, my head was the root... Not the "Belly" what causes to be unable to move the head... Here's what i made http://i.imgur.com/Xx7byHx.png

Comment: (Ran out of character...) Thank you for your kind answers! I hope i'll get more support from this forum :) I want to learn more about 3D Modelling in Blender. Ou, and sorry for my bad english :D This is not my native language ^_^

Regards ^^