# How to join more bones in a armature together

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, rigify

I'm tryng to rig a face. I would like to join/parent more bones together,but I'm not able to do it. I've already tried using the approach explained here :

[Join bones in a armature?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21239/join-bones-in-a-armature)

but it didn't work for me...check the attached picture,please. In the red circles you see the bones that I want to be attach together. The armature is the one provided by the `Rigify Addon PitchiPoy Version`,that I found here :

http://pitchipoy.tv/?p=2026

[image: bones to attach]

problem is that when I parent one side of the bone,the other side is disconnected from the rest of the bones and sometimes one bone is placed in the wrong place...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connected bones are a Parent/child relationship: a Parent can have lots of childrens but a child can have only one parent: from the tip of a bone you can extrude (or connect) more than one bone, but you can't connect two or more bones to the base of another bone (it would have more than one parent).

Usually a complex facial rig is made of shapekeys; each shape key can be controlled by one or more bones using drivers: so you will have a rig made of deforming bones (the classic way) and non deforming bones (to drive shape keys).

Don't be afraid of drivers: they look more complicated than they are, and they're very very useful.