# how to fix this rigging problem

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

I have studied Blender for a while now, and I just started rigging and then this problem occurred:

[image]

The main bone is not connected to the main body bone, and I have tried to parent it to the main body bone to no avail.

P.S: This is my first post on this site so I have no clue how things work around here so forgive me if there is grammar/mistake in the question I asked, and please note that English is not my first language :D

Comment: This might help you http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21239/join-bones-in-a-armature and your English is better than some native speakers ;-)

Comment: No problem, if the link doesn't help, edit your question to explain why for more speedy responses  ;-)

Comment: @root i know :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first guess would be that you're trying to do parenting in Pose mode. Switch to Edit mode on your armature and you should be able to parent bones without problem.

Comment: though the problem is already fixed, i gave my sincere thanks to thee ;D